# assertText in Selenium IDE: always true, due to target being display:none

Tags: selenium-ide

My webapp has a display:none div with the text "request ok". When the Ajax request is done, this becomes display:block and so it's shown to the user.

I'm using assertText via Selenium IDE to test this page, but the assert never fails, due to the fact that the div always exists.

Do a assertTextIsShown()-like function exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following command to test the visibility of the text:

```
<tr>
    <td>assertVisible</td>
    <td>locator</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```